# Inequalities for trace of product of symmetric positive definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace, symmetric-matrices

Consider symmetric positive definite matrices of same size $A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_m$. Is the following statement true?

$$ Tr(\prod_{i=1}^m A_i) \leq \prod_{i=1}^m Tr(A_i)$$

My guess is it's true based on the following fact from Wikipedia:

If $A, B > 0$ and of same size, then

$$ 0 \leq [tr(AB)]^2 \leq tr(A^2)tr(B^2) \leq [tr(A)]^2 [tr(B)]^2$$

Comment: yes, look up the sub-multiplicativity of the Schatten 1-norm aka nuclear norm.  The relationships is $Tr\Big(\prod_{i=1}^m A_i\Big) \leq  \Big\Vert \prod_{i=1}^m A_i \Big\Vert_{S_1}\leq  \prod_{i=1}^m \Big\Vert A_i \Big\Vert_{S_1}  = \prod_{i=1}^m Tr \Big (A_i \Big)$

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we can easily extend your theorem by repeatedly applying the inequality like this (I'm a bit too lazy to formally work out the formal induction, let me know if you need help for that):

$tr(ABC)^2 \leq tr(AB)^2 tr(B)^2 \leq tr(A)^2 tr(B)^2 tr(C)^2$

Secondly, the trace of any matrix is equal to the sum of its eigenvalues. Since all eigenvalues in a positive definite matrix are positive, the sum of eigenvalues (hence the trace) is also positive.

So since $tr(ABC...)^2 \leq tr(A)^2 \cdot tr(B)^2 \cdot tr(C)^2...$
and since we know that all individual matrix traces are positive, we can just remove the squares (doesn't matter whether $tr(ABC...)$ is negative or positive).

Hence $tr(ABC...) \leq tr(A)\cdot tr(B) \cdot tr(C) ...$, which proves your theorem.